# Does ASP.NET MVC Framework support asynchronous page execution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC Framework, From some articles like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/03/17/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request.aspx), it seems that MvcHandler has only Execute() implemented, there is no asynchronous API implemented. Actually, I don't think Controller has asynchronous API either.

So, ASP.NET MVC doesn't support asynchronous programming? this could be a big hurdle to scalability if the web page needs I/O operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, async support is not built into MVC. It's on the feature list, but no guarantees as to exactly when it might be released (and in what form).

Comment: As an update: ASP.NET MVC 2 now has Asnyc Controller support. Here's the documentation 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(VS.100,printer).aspx

Answer (score 7):

After some googling, I found this terrific blog about how to DIY asynchronous ASP.NET MVC. The implementation looks easy and straightforward. I am wondering why ASP.NET MVC team doesn't have this feature at the first time.

http://blog.codeville.net/2008/04/05/improve-scalability-in-aspnet-mvc-using-asynchronous-requests/

Comment: There's a cut line for features, and inevitably a feature somebody wanted ends up below the cut line. There are tons of "easy and straightforward" things that won't get into v1 because time is not infinite. :)

Answer (score 3):

MVC 2 supports asynchronous page execution via AsyncController.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Brad mentioned, Microsoft is working on a solution as part of MVC futures. There is also an implementation at: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AsyncMvc/Wiki/View.aspx?id=11350

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC 2 has now incorporated asnyc controller from the beat release. Check it out.