# How to Make ASP.NET MVC Recognize IHttpAsyncHandler from IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, ihttpasynchandler, iroutehandler

In this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275545/does-aspnet-mvc-framework-support-asynchronous-page-execution), I found one way to make ASP.NET MVC support asynchronous processing. However, I cannot make it work.

Basically, the idea is to create a new implementation of IRouteHandler which has only one method ***GetHttpHandler***. The ***GetHttpHandler*** method should return an `IHttpAsyncHandler` implementation instead of just `IHttpHandler`, because `IHttpAsyncHandler` has Begin/EndXXXX pattern API.

```
public class AsyncMvcRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new AsyncMvcHandler(requestContext);
    }

    class AsyncMvcHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public AsyncMvcHandler(RequestContext context)
        {
        }

        // IHttpHandler members
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        // IHttpAsyncHandler members
        public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the RegisterRoutes method of file Global.asax.cs, register this class ***AsyncMvcRouteHandler***.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}", new AsyncMvcRouteHandler())
    {
        Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }),
    });
}
```

I set breakpoint at ***ProcessRequest***, ***BeginProcessRequest*** and ***EndProcessRequest***. Only ***ProcessRequest*** is executed. In another word, even though ***AsyncMvcHandler*** implements ***IHttpAsyncHandler***. ASP.NET MVC doesn't know that and just handle it as an `IHttpHandler` implementation.

How to make ASP.NET MVC treat ***AsyncMvcHandler*** as ***IHttpAsyncHandler*** so we can have asynchronous page processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of hassle with the code, I found out the issue.

In my Visual Studio 2008, when I press Ctrl+F5, the Application Development Server is launched and IE is popped up to access "http://localhost:3573/". In this case, the sync API ***ProcessRequest*** is invoked. The stack trace is like this.

> > MyMvcApplication.DLL!MyMvcApplication.AsyncMvcRouteHandler.AsyncMvcHandler.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext
> >     httpContext =
> >     {System.Web.HttpContext}) Line 59 C# 
> >       System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler.VerifyAndProcessRequest(System.Web.IHttpHandler
> >     httpHandler,
> >     System.Web.HttpContextBase
> >     httpContext) + 0x19 bytes
> >       System.Web.Routing.dll!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContextBase
> >     httpContext) + 0x66 bytes
> >       System.Web.Routing.dll!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext
> >     httpContext) + 0x28 bytes
> >       System.Web.Routing.dll!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext
> >     context) + 0x8 bytes
> >       MyMvcApplication.DLL!MyMvcApplication._Default.Page_Load(object
> >     sender = {ASP.default_aspx},
> >     System.EventArgs e =
> >     {System.EventArgs}) Line 13 + 0x1a
> >     bytes C#

However, when I change the URL in IE to be "http://localhost:3573/whatever.mvc", it hits the ***BeginProcessRequest***. The stack trace is like this.

> > MyMvcApplication.DLL!MyMvcApplication.AsyncMvcRouteHandler.AsyncMvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext
> >     context = {System.Web.HttpContext},
> >     System.AsyncCallback cb = {Method =
> >     {Void
> >     OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(System.IAsyncResult)}},
> >     object extraData = null) Line 66  C# 
> >       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> >     + 0x249 bytes     System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep
> >     step =
> >     {System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep},
> >     ref bool completedSynchronously =
> >     true) + 0x9c bytes
> >       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception
> >     error) + 0x133 bytes
> >       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext
> >     context, System.AsyncCallback cb,
> >     object extraData) + 0x7c bytes
> >       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest
> >     wr =
> >     {Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request})
> >     + 0x17c bytes     System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest
> >     wr) + 0x63 bytes
> >       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest
> >     wr) + 0x47 bytes
> >       WebDev.WebHost.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process()
> >     + 0xf1 bytes      WebDev.WebHost.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection
> >     conn) + 0x4e bytes

It seems that only url with ".mvc" suffix can make asynchronous API invoked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, however I found that it was because my catch all route handler:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                                  
    "{controller}/{action}",                           
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }  
);
```

Was picking up the request, not the custom route I added that dealt with the async route handler. Perhaps by using the .mvc in your custom route defintion you created a distinction so that it was used rather than the synchronous catch-all.

Comment: What was your custom async route handler exactly? We are getting a similar issue but we have no catch-all default route handler (all the routes are opt-in)

Comment: Sorry I don't remember, 5 years ago... different life in tech time.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this in the past, I manage to either get the view to render and then all the async tasks would finish.  Or the async tasks to finish but the view would not render.

I created a RouteCollectionExtensions based on the original MVC code.  In my AsyncMvcHandler, I had an empty method (no exception) for ProcessMethod.

Comment: Hi MrJavaGuy,

When I leave ProcessRequest empty, it just doesn't do any rendering on returned web page. 
How do you do to make asynchronous BeginProcessRequest/EndProcessRequest get invoked?

Comment: Do to an NDA, I can only give a hint, look at IActionInvoker.